# Unwanted characters in output of Hadoop job

Tags: hadoop

I wrote a simple program to gather some statistics about bigrams in some data.
I print statistics to a custom file.

```
Path file = new Path(context.getConfiguration().get("mapred.output.dir") + "/bigram.txt");
FSDataOutputStream out = file.getFileSystem(context.getConfiguration()).create(file);
```

My code has following lines:

```
Text.writeString(out, "total number of unique bigrams: " + uniqBigramCount + "\n");
Text.writeString(out, "total number of bigrams: " + totalBigramCount + "\n");
Text.writeString(out, "number of bigrams that appear only once: " + onceBigramCount + "\n");
```

I get following output in vim/gedit:

```
'total number of unique bigrams: 424462
!total number of bigrams: 1578220
0number of bigrams that appear only once: 296139
```

Apart from unwanted characters at the beginning of the lines, there are some non-printing characters too. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: I believe it is the length of the string (that is written in the front) that is causing some binary skew.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: No, I removed the strings written in front, for e.g. I changed the first print statement to `Text.writeString(out, uniqBigramCount + "\n");`. I got following output:

^G424462
^H1578220
^G296139

The unwanted characters are still present.

Comment: What I was referring to was the internal behaviour of the Text not what you are passing, this is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ThomasJungblut says, the writeString method writes out two values for each call to writeString - the length of the string (as a vint) and the String bytes:

```
/** Write a UTF8 encoded string to out
 */
public static int writeString(DataOutput out, String s) throws IOException {
  ByteBuffer bytes = encode(s);
  int length = bytes.limit();
  WritableUtils.writeVInt(out, length);
  out.write(bytes.array(), 0, length);
  return length;
}
```

If you just want to be able to print textual output to this file (i.e. all human readable), then i suggest you wrap the `out` variable with a `PrintStream`, and use the println or printf methods:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out);
ps.printf("total number of unique bigrams: %d\n", uniqBigramCount);
ps.printf("total number of bigrams: %d\n", totalBigramCount);
ps.printf("number of bigrams that appear only once: %d\n", onceBigramCount);
ps.close();
```

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut and Chris: Thanks for the answers, Chris's suggestion worked.